# Pass parameters in AccessToken post request for gem Oauth rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth

I am trying do POST API call for AccessToken class of gem Oauth. But I am getting weird responses so can anyone please let me know what is the exact way for making post call.

**Implementation-1:**

```
access_token.post('/organizations/223031/files', { 'name' => '10.3.199_export.zip' }.to_json(),
{ 'Accept'=>'application/vnd.deere.axiom.v3+json', 'Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.deere.axiom.v3+json' })
```

I am getting the correct response.

**Implementation-2:**

```
access_token.post('/organizations/223031/files',
:body => {:name => 'xyz.zip'}.to_json,
:headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.deere.axiom.v3+json', 'Accept'=>'application/vnd.deere.axiom.v3+json'})
```

For this call I referred this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333286/ruby-on-rails-how-to-use-oauth2accesstoken-post), but getting the 404 error.

So I have a following doubts:

- As per my understanding *implementation-1* is correct (correct me if I am wrong) as for this getting the correct response where as for *implementation-2* getting the 404 error. So what is the actual difference between them.
- What is the best way for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gotta use the string hash rocket for `:body` and `:headers`, I like **Implementation-1** better though.

```
access_token.post('/organizations/223031/files',
  "body" => {"name" => 'xyz.zip'},
  "headers" => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.deere.axiom.v3+json', 
    'Accept'=>'application/vnd.deere.axiom.v3+json'})
```